# What will be /how to set the threshold values for a page fault/sec for any server?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, operating-system

Currently I am working on the page fault issue on server. I am getting some of the readings with my tool. Some readings are very high like `400 pagefaults/sec` and some have low as `30 or 40 pagefaults/sec`.

In this case, I need to check some threshold values for page faults. Either it is of major or minor or invalid type of threshold. I googled this issue but cant get a info for same.

How can I set such a threshold values based on readings per second?

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the number of page faults per second directly (and I'm pretty sure there isn't a control for that), you'll make the code run slower, much much slower and I doubt that's what you want.

If the page fault rate is too high, it means your server does not have enough RAM, which causes it to use virtual/on-disk memory. It can also be a sign of memory leaks. You should look into that instead of trying to lower the page fault rate. The observed rate is not the cause, it's the effect and you should nail down the cause and fix it.